# Tomcat docBase with versioned deploy

Tags: tomcat7

Now I usually deploy a web app as ROOT in tomcat 7.
I want map a folder that contains images, pdf and so on, and I use ad alias

so my server.xml contains this:

```
<Context path=""  docBase="ROOT"
         aliases="/tomcat-reources=/C:/Workspace/path-to-tomcat/tomcat-resources" 
         reloadable="true"/>
```

and I'm able to show resources in C:/Workspace/path-to-tomcat/tomcat-resources

in urls, such as

```
<img src="/tomcat-reources/googfy.png" />
```

I have the problem when I try to version the app, calling the war like 
ROOT#20180925.war:
the web app is deployed, but links to tomcat-reources do not work

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a good solution, so my workaroud is manage static resourcs by web server (I use nginx)